# Use returned rows as php variable names, and assign values from CSV

Tags: php, mysql, loops, csv, multiple-columns

I have a mysql `SELECT` query that returns the following:

```
$getDbVars = "SELECT `var_code` FROM `campaign_variables`";

$name
$videoURL
$leadLogo
$brand
$competitor
```

I also have a CSV, whose columns are the same as above. And of course CSV holds several hundred rows for each column.

```
andres,http://somewhere.com/vid1.mp4,http://somewhere.com/logo1.png,brand1,andres-competitor
allan,http://somewhere.com/vid5.mp4,http://somewhere.com/logo5.png,brand5,allan-competitor
alexander,http://somewhere.com/vid7.mp4,http://somewhere.com/logo7.png,alexander-competitor
```

First, I need to use whatever the sql query returns as variable names.

Then, I need to be able to loop through the CSV, and each time assign value into those variables. So that, for example, in the first scan of the loop:

```
$name = 'andres';
$videoURL = 'http://somewhere.com/vid1.mp4';
$leadLogo = 'http://somewhere.com/logo1.png';
$brand = 'brand1';
$competitor = 'andres-competitor';
```

and so on, for each row of the CSV.

Please let me know if the above isn't making much sense. The reason I have to do it this way is because there are situations when that same query will return a different number of rows. Therefore, there will be different "variable names". Good thing is that the CSV will always have the same number of columns as the number of rows the query returns.

Comment: Please elaborate. Show some sample csv-rows and the select query and what the result should look like.

Comment: `list($name, $videoURL, ...) = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)`, basically. what you want is basic PHP and database operations. You're probably just overthinking everything.

Comment: @TobiasKun thanks, I added more details

Comment: HI @MarcB Wish I could, but I don't think I could do that. There will definitely be instances when for other people using it, that same query will return very different data, and will give me a different number of variables, as they will be using different CSV's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve this are arrays:

```
$keys = array("name", "videoURL", "leadLogo", "brand", "competitor");
$csv = $your_csv_as_array_data;

$data = array();
foreach($csv as $row) {
    $temp = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($keys); $i++) {
        $temp[$keys[$i]] = $row[$i];
    }
    $data[] = $temp;
}
```

This will give you the following array:

```
array (
    [0] => array(
        "name" => "...",
        "videoURL" => "...",
        "leadLogo" => "...",
        "brand" => "...",
        "competitor" => "..."
    ),
    [1] => array(
        "name" => "...",
        "videoURL" => "...",
        "leadLogo" => "...",
        "brand" => "...",
        "competitor" => "..."
    ),
    [2] => array(
        "name" => "...",
        "videoURL" => "...",
        "leadLogo" => "...",
        "brand" => "...",
        "competitor" => "..."
    )
    .
    .
    .
)
```